# How to sync Ovi files with Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, google-sync

I just signed in to Ovi Files service and it works great on Windows Desktop. But it lacks a connector for Linux. Is there any alternative way to achieve the same.
The goal is to sync your files on the desktop with a webstorage system like Google Docs or Ovi files, Dropbox and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Google docs:
http://code.google.com/p/gdocsuploader/
http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-upload/
Dropbox:
http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20262 (Using experimental is advised on Linux)
Uhm that's it I guess. (You can also use [Ubuntu one](https://one.ubuntu.com/)).

Comment: Thanks, gdocsuploader is an interesting application. However it does not quite do what I need. I am looking more for a sync app to be able to keep 3 computers (1 desktop and 2 laps) in sync via web. Ovi files is really nice but lacks an Ubuntu connector.

Comment: Well.. what about Dropbox? oO

Comment: Yes, Dropbox is a good option. Its only drawback is the need to have a dedicated offline folder, whereas Ovi Files keeps reachability to all your docs and has the handy and cool "any time" feature.
Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm you could keep a cron job with rsync to keep them in sync. Or simply work into the Dropbox folder (Dropbox users tend to do that, like I put my VS files there. On linux you can simply hardlink them I guess.)